# How can I get ID or attr from a SPAN?

Tags: imacros

I want to write a script with imacro to delete my phone number on my google email.
My problem is i cannot get the id of delete button, when i view source code I just see a span with attr but the text is encoded so I cannot get the text? So please help me to solved problem? To easy understand I upload the image in attach file, please help me to solved.

Thanks you[image]

Comment: I believe that it would be easier to use [Relative Positioning](https://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction#Extract_with_relative_Positioning) by making an anchor on: `TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:Your<SP>phone<SP>number`

Answer (score 0):

you can catch element also by class name

try this code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:DPvwYc<SP>MRcnif
```